# Using Ubuntu in a business context

Tags: license, legal

Do I need any special license to use Ubuntu in business? I know it's free for home users, but I couldn't find a definitive answer on whether I can use it for business without any special license.

Answer (score 5):

Ubuntu is free for everyone to use, individuals or entities. For more information please contact Canonical: https://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/contact-us

Community support, including AskUbuntu, is also free. Professional support, if required, is paid. Please check the [Ubuntu Advantage pricing](https://www.ubuntu.com/support/plans-and-pricing).